# How to position a custom Popup using other components' positions

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I have a custom Popup:

```kotlin
        if (expanded) {
            Popup(
                onDismissRequest = {},
                properties = PopupProperties(
                    clippingEnabled = false
                ),
                popupPositionProvider = object : PopupPositionProvider {
                    override fun calculatePosition(
                        anchorBounds: IntRect,
                        windowSize: IntSize,
                        layoutDirection: LayoutDirection,
                        popupContentSize: IntSize
                    ): IntOffset {
                        return IntOffset(
                            x = textXPosition,
                            y = barYPosition
                        )
                    }
                }
            ) {
                Text(
                    text = "This is the popup content.",
                    modifier = Modifier.background(Color.White)
                )
            }
        }
```

where **textXPosition** and **barYPosition** are determined at follows:

---

**textXPosition**:

```kotlin
        var textXPosition by remember { mutableStateOf(0) }

        Text(
            text = state.currentFileName,
            modifier = Modifier
                .weight(1f)
                .padding(start = 8.dp)
                .clickable { expanded = !expanded }
                .onGloballyPositioned { coordinates ->
                    textXPosition = coordinates.positionInRoot().x.toInt()
                }
        )

        if (expanded) {...}
```

---

**barYPosition**:

```kotlin
    var barYPosition by remember {
        mutableStateOf(0)
    }

    ActionBar(
        modifier = Modifier
            .height(36.dp)
            .background(Color(0xfffafafa))
            .onGloballyPositioned { coordinates ->
                barYPosition = coordinates.positionInRoot().y.toInt()
            }
    ...)
```

---

What I get in the end is on the picture:

[image]

The idea was that the popup would be directly above the text, but there's actually a small gap and I have no idea why..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you anchor PopUp and your content inside a Box and set offset by height of PopUp to up it should work as expected.

[image]

```
@Preview
@Composable
private fun Test() {

    var barYPosition by remember {
        mutableStateOf(0)
    }

    Column(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize().background(Color.Black)
    ) {

        TopAppBar(
            modifier = Modifier
                .height(36.dp)
                .background(Color(0xfffafafa))
        ) {

        }
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.weight(1f))


        Box(
            modifier = Modifier.border(2.dp, Color.Red)
        ) {

            Popup(
                onDismissRequest = {},
                offset = IntOffset(0, y = -barYPosition),
                properties = PopupProperties(
                    clippingEnabled = false
                )
            ) {
                Text(
                    text = "This is the popup content.",
                    modifier = Modifier.background(Color.White)
                        .onPlaced {
                            barYPosition = it.size.height
                        }
                )
            }
            Row(
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth().background(Color.White),
                verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
            ) {
                Text(
                    "Some Text Needed",
                    fontSize = 24.sp
                )
                Spacer(modifier = Modifier.weight(1f))

                Icon(imageVector = Icons.Default.Settings, contentDescription = null)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That does utilize the height of the popup content to dynamically adjust its position, which makes sure the popup is placed exactly where it should be, irrespective of any other layout parameters or potential paddings/margins that might affect the position. Simpler than my answer. Upvoted.

Comment: This doesn't work for me sadly. There's a bigger gap for some reason

Comment: Do you see gap when you test this sample? If that's the case you should update compose version to 1.5.0 or above, version i tested is 1.5.1, because there was a vertical boundary limit where you can position popup in early versions.

Answer (score 0):

That gap could potentially be occurring due to several reasons including paddings, margins, or other layout modifiers affecting the final positioning.

You might need to account for these additional spaces when calculating the `x` and `y` positions for your `Popup`.

Adjust the `y` coordinate to position the popup above the text by subtracting the height of the text from the `barYPosition`.

First, find the height of the text component, which can be acquired in a similar manner to how you found `textXPosition` and `barYPosition`.

```kotlin
var textHeight by remember { mutableStateOf(0) }

Text(
    //...
    .onGloballyPositioned { coordinates ->
        textXPosition = coordinates.positionInRoot().x.toInt()
        textHeight = coordinates.size.height
    }
)
```

Then, modify your `PopupPositionProvider` to add the `textHeight` from `barYPosition` to correctly position the popup above the text:

```kotlin
return IntOffset(
    x = textXPosition,
    y = barYPosition + textHeight
)
```

Consider  also the size of the popup content. Adjust the `y` coordinate further by adding the height of the popup content:

```kotlin
return IntOffset(
    x = textXPosition,
    y = barYPosition + textHeight + popupContentSize.height
)
```

I would recommend trying out these steps incrementally and verifying the position of the `Popup` at each step to pinpoint the cause of the gap.

---

The OP adds:

> It should be plus, not minus because otherwise the gap gets bigger. And sadly that's not it - the popup comes down too much

To position the popup correctly, it seems we need to take a different approach.

One possibility is that the gap is appearing because of the height of the [`ActionBar`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar). Try to add the height of the `ActionBar` to the `barYPosition`.

First, find out the height of the `ActionBar`:

```kotlin
var actionBarHeight by remember { mutableStateOf(0) }

ActionBar(
    modifier = Modifier
        .height(36.dp)
        .background(Color(0xfffafafa))
        .onGloballyPositioned { coordinates ->
            barYPosition = coordinates.positionInRoot().y.toInt()
            actionBarHeight = coordinates.size.height
        }
    //...
)
```

Then, use this `actionBarHeight` in your popup position calculation:

```kotlin
override fun calculatePosition(
    anchorBounds: IntRect,
    windowSize: IntSize,
    layoutDirection: LayoutDirection,
    popupContentSize: IntSize
): IntOffset {
    return IntOffset(
        x = textXPosition,
        y = barYPosition + actionBarHeight
    )
}
```

That adjustment should move the popup down, closer to the desired position. You might need to adjust it further by adding or subtracting some fixed offset to get it exactly right:

```kotlin
y = barYPosition + actionBarHeight + offset
```

Make sure to fine-tune the `offset` value through testing to achieve the exact positioning you are aiming for. Adjust it incrementally until you find a value that gives you the desired result.

Comment: It should be plus, not minus because otherwise the gap gets bigger. And sadly that's not it - the popup comes down too much.

Comment: @SebastianLore OK. I have edited the answer accordingly, and included a new suggestion.